# Transfer files between Linux ec2 instance and windows ec2 instance programatically

Tags: java, windows, linux, amazon-ec2, file-transfer

I want  to send a file from linux instance to windows instance. Then after processing that file in windows instance, i have to send the file back to the linux instance. I am using java in both the ends. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest and most cost efficient way is to create an [Amazon Elastic Block Store](http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/), attach that to both instances and then do all file I/O operations through the persisted disk.

Comment: I dont think you can add a single EBS to 2 instances.

Answer (score 0):

You can use samba on the linux OS.

1. Shared a directory on the Windows OS
2. Allow the linux IP to access on this (read and write)
3. Mount this directory on the linux with samba

Then you can read and write file on the Windows OS now.